# Rename url id to readable format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-routing

I storing each post in firebase with firebase auto generate id. let say this `-JBuEJXgILubWjxECjwj`

then I query the post like this

`Post.getPost($routeParams.postID); //snippet code`

so when user visit `example.com/userid/-JBuEJXgILubWjxECjwj` will show the content. But I want the url readable.

When user visit `example.com/userid/mystory` or `example/userid/-JBuEJXgILubWjxECjwj` will get the correct post.

How to rename the id to title in url?

**UPDATE**

Basically, this is how my data store in firebase

```
posts: {
  randomID1: {
   title: 'This is post 1'
  },
  randomID2: {
   title: 'This is post 2
  }
}
```

Then, I query using [angularFire](http://angularfire.com) javascript api ($firebase)

```
$scope.post = $firebase(new Firebase.child('posts/').child($routeParams.postID))
```

I think the query code is normal, just how my data store for me to convert id to title.
any idea?

Comment: Can you keep a key value store of ids and URL slugs, use the slug for any navigation and look up the id in the store when you need to get a post?

Comment: @imcg could you give me an example of how to?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but if you post some of the code you're using I'll try.

Comment: @imcg I updated the qeustion, please take a look. thank u

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to convert the titles to URL slugs and then look up the Id (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvWhV/):

```
var posts = {
  randomID1: {
   title: 'This is post 1'
  },
  randomID2: {
   title: 'This is post 2'
  }
};

// find id from slug in posts
function getPostId(slug) {
  for(var i in posts) {
    // match id or slug so both URL forms are supported
    if(i === slug || posts[i].slug === slug) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// create slugs and add them to post objects
for(var i in posts) {
  var p = posts[i];
  // create slug by replacing characters in title. TODO: handle posts with same title, maybe by appending a number
  p.slug = p.title.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();

  // make a link to the post
  var link = document.createElement('li');
  link.innerText = p.title;
  link.setAttribute('id', p.slug);
  link.onclick = function() {
    var slug = this.getAttribute('id');
    alert('slug:' + slug + ' id:' + getPostId(slug));
  };
  document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

To use it with the router, do something like:

```
var postId = getPostId($routeParams.slug);
$scope.post = $firebase(new Firebase.child('posts/').child(postID));
```

Comment: this quite complicated. I'll skip 1st. Will let you know when i'm there.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it's far more complicated within the context of the application. Good luck!

Comment: This assumes that you have downloaded all posts fron firebase, right?